# can we initialCameraPosition in GoogleMap - Flutter

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

how can we setup initial camera positions in googleMap i.e. instead of hard code lat/lang (below code)

```
GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(30.666, 76.8127),
            zoom: 15
          ),
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.hybrid, 
          compassEnabled: true,
          trackCameraPosition: true,
      )
```

I just want my current location lat/lang instead of hard coded values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location) package.

Here is an example.

```
var currentLocation = LocationData;

var location = new Location();

// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
error = 'Permission denied';
}
currentLocation = null;
}
```

And then

```
var location = new Location();   location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
print(currentLocation.latitude);
print(currentLocation.longitude);
})
```

Comment: LocationData not found, do I need to something else, I already have import 'package:location/location.dart'

Comment: Have you updated `gradle.properties` and `build.gradle` and `manifest` according to the docs??

Comment: Did my answer worked for you, or are you still facing issue.

Comment: still facing issue,  I am not able to setup current lat lan instead of LatLng(30.666, 76.8127).

Comment: If you are facing issue with package ask in another post or in github, please accept the answer if it helped you.